Has the log added by SYSCALL_DEFINE4 not been printed to the debug serial port?
The Linux system I customized sometimes cannot be restarted when using the reboot command, so I added printing to both the busybox and kernel. When I use the serial port to check the logs of the reboot execution, I only see the printing added in the busybox and not the printing added in the kernel. What is the problem?
I am currently using the kernel of Linux 3.10, the processor of ARM v7, and the version of busybox is 1.25.1.
SYSCALL_DEFINE4(reboot, int, magic1, int, magic2, unsigned int, cmd,
                void __user *, arg)
{
        printk(KERN_EMERG "enter SYSCALL_DEFINE4\n");
        struct pid_namespace *pid_ns = task_active_pid_ns(current);
        char buffer[256];
        int ret = 0;

        /* We only trust the superuser with rebooting the system. */
        if (!ns_capable(pid_ns->user_ns, CAP_SYS_BOOT))
                return -EPERM;
        ...
        ...
        ...
}

# sysctl kernel.printk
kernel.printk = 0       4       1       7

